# Como leer JSON de una dirección externa en JS

Tags: javascript, json

No se si en JS es la mejor forma pero me gustaría saber como hacerlo...

La siguiente dirección me devuelve un JSON:

```
https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/mineshurs.duckdns.org:25648
```

Me devuelve exactamente esto:

[image: Lo que devuelve la direccion del json]

Y lo que necesito saber es como leer ese json con JS para luego mostrar los datos que necesite de ese JSON

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres hacer, serías tan amable de editar y dar mas detalles por favor?

Comment: Ya está modificado @Aprendiz

Comment: ¿Has investigado / intentando algo? ¿Qué dificultad concreta tienes en tu intento? Esto es algo relativamente fácil de hacer usando [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) por ejemplo (una API moderna de Javascript) o bien mediante Ajax. Precisamente en la doc sobre `fetch` hay ejemplos de un json obtenido desde una URL.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya han comentado la mejor forma es con fetch, te dejo un ejemplo usando tu url:

```
// Se hace el fetch a tu url
fetch('https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/mineshurs.duckdns.org:25648')
.then(function(response) {
    // Si todo sale bien en la promesa se devuelve el json de la respuesta
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
    // si existe myJson.players.list se agregan al contenedor los elementos de list
    if (myJson.players.list) {
        // Aqui se obtiene un elemento del dom que me he inventado donde podrias mostrar los datos, este debe existir en tu html 
        const contenedor = document.querySelector('#mi-contenedor');
        myJson.players.list.map((player) => {
            contenedor.innerHTML += `<li>${player}</li>`;
        });
    }
});
```

El ejemplo lo he sacado de la documentación de mozilla.org para el método fecth 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch

Esto por supuesto es código javascript que debe ir en un archivo .js o entre etiquetas <script>.